# How do i use stride in webgl?

Tags: javascript, memory, 3d, floating-point, webgl

```
//Defining geometry
var vertices = [
    +0.0,+0.0,+0.0,
    +0.0,+0.0,+1.0,

    -0.5,+0.0,+0.0,
    +1.0,+0.0,+0.0, 

    -0.5,-0.5,+0.0,
    +0.0,+1.0,+0.0,

    +0.5,+0.5,+0.0,
    +1.0,+0.0,+1.0, 

    +0.5,+0.0,+0.0,
    +1.0,+1.0,+0.0, 

    -0.5,+0.5,+0.0
    +1.0,+0.0,+1.0
];



indices = [3,4,0,0,2,1,5,0,1];

var VextexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();

webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VextexBuffer);

webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);

var coord = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"coordinates");

webgl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,6 * 4,0);

webgl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);

var color = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");

webgl.vertexAttribPointer(color, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,6 * 4,3 * 4);

webgl.enableVertexAttribArray(color);       


var IndexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();

webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);

webgl.bufferData(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

I want to use stride in VertexAttribPointer method to use a single VBO for both vertex and color data rather than using 2 VBOs but the problem is i don't know the size of a float in javascript. So i assumed it to be 4.

Now i am getting this error:-

```
**[.CommandBufferContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements:        
attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1**
```

i think the problem is in :-

```
webgl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,6 * 4,0);
```

and :-

```
webgl.vertexAttribPointer(color, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,6 * 4,3 * 4);
```

Please tell where the fault is ?
THANKS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of a FLOAT is 4 in WebGL. It has nothing to do with numbers or floats JavaScript. Floats/numbers in JavaScript are separate from Floats in WebGL buffers.

Where is your draw call? It's not clear from the code above what's wrong. It looks correct at a glance

Testing it below I found 1, issue. You were missing a comma between the last coordinate and the last color which means your `vertices` array was one value short

```js
var webgl = document.querySelector("#c").getContext("webgl");
var shaderProgram = twgl.createProgramFromScripts(webgl, ["vs", "fs"]);
webgl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

//Defining geometry
var vertices = [
    +0.0,+0.0,+0.0,
    +0.0,+0.0,+1.0,

    -0.5,+0.0,+0.0,
    +1.0,+0.0,+0.0, 

    -0.5,-0.5,+0.0,
    +0.0,+1.0,+0.0,

    +0.5,+0.5,+0.0,
    +1.0,+0.0,+1.0, 

    +0.5,+0.0,+0.0,
    +1.0,+1.0,+0.0, 

    -0.5,+0.5,+0.0,
    +1.0,+0.0,+1.0
];


indices = [3,4,0,0,2,1,5,0,1];

var VextexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();

webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VextexBuffer);

webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);

var coord = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"coordinates");

webgl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,6 * 4,0);

webgl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);

var color = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");

webgl.vertexAttribPointer(color, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,6 * 4,3 * 4);

webgl.enableVertexAttribArray(color);       


var IndexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();

webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);

webgl.bufferData(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);

webgl.drawElements(webgl.TRIANGLES, 6, webgl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
attribute vec4 coordinates;
attribute vec4 color;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
  gl_Position = coordinates;
  v_color = color;
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 v_color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
</script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```